# Composite functions, Inverse functions, and bijections

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$. Suppose $g, h:B \rightarrow A$ so that $f \circ g = I_B$ and $h \circ f = I_A$. Show that $f$ is a bijections and $g=h=f^{-1}$.

$I_A $ and $ I_B$ denote the identity functions for sets $A$ and $B$.

I've been working on this one for a while now, and don't really understand how to show it

Comment: Have you allready managed to prove injectivity and surjectivity (applying the hint of John)?

Comment: You're hit was helpful

Comment: See also: [Inverse of a Function exists iff Function is bijective](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994282/inverse-of-a-function-exists-iff-function-is-bijective) and other related posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$h=h\circ I_B=h\circ(f\circ g)=(h\circ f)\circ g=I_A\circ g=g$$

surjectivity:

> $b=f(g(b))$ for each $b\in B$

injectivity:

> If $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ then $a_1=h(f(a_1))=h(f(a_2))=a_2$

Comment: After the first line of this answer, it would suffice to say: the map $g=h$ satisfies the defintion of inverse map of $f$, and by its existence $f$ is automatically bijective. One does not even have to mention elements (the proof is valid in any category, if one replaces "bijection" by "isomorphism").

Comment: @Marc That is correct. It is informative though in the sense that it shows on what this "automatically bijective" is based. Actually it shows that in category **Sets** the isomorphisms are exactly the bijections. It might be redundant, but that also depends on the knowledge of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

To show that $f$ is a bijection, it suffices to show that it's injective and surjective. Try to use $f\circ g = I_B$ to show that $f$ is surjective and $h\circ f = I_A$ to show that $f$ is injective.