# Suppose A, B and C are sets such that #A=#B. Is it true that #(A x C) =#(B x C)? If it is, prove that.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm sure that this is true, because A and B have the same cardinality (number of elements in the set). So there has to be the same number of ordered pairs with C in both cases. But I'm not sure how to exactly prove it since we just started with cardinality.

Comment: See also [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429019/cartesian-product-of-bijective-functions-is-bijective) and other questions [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1429019).

Answer (score 5):

You just need a bijection between $A \times C$ and $B \times C$ given a bijection  between $A$ and $B$.

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a bijection. Then define $g: A \times C \rightarrow B \times C$ given by $g(a,c)=(f(a),c).$

Answer (score 0):

A*c= A*c ( for any value)

Now given that
a=b
Now we can replace the right hand side "a" of this given equation with its value B, Then equation will be

A*C = B*C (proved)